# Doubts on using phonegap and titanium

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, titanium, titanium-mobile

Recently i heard about the PhoneGap and Titanium mobile web app developments. I had analyzed about both the web applications and got some idea of how to use and what are the strength and weakness of these. Yet i didn't get some clear ideas on the following questions,

- Does these web app developments supports XML Parsing?
- I heard about these use html5, javascript and css alone. Does it supports Ajax?
- If my App retrieves Remote XML file. Is there a way to Parse the elements?
- How much these PhoneGap and Titanium supports Web services? Can i have a way to implement Restful Web services.

Can anyone provide me suggestions on these questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phone gap is no match for titanium. Titanium Ultimate single code base scripting language.

if u want really have native app experience try titanium. we are doing projects in it . it is ultimate has such experience and tools and community.

if u want try with html5 coding then phonegap is fine.

but in titanium you go deep in and you can understand the mobile concept as they were in native app..
my suggestion go with titanium.....You will love it

coming to your question

Absolutly you can use remotecall get data.both xml and json parsing are there.

see the link http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.XML

before see the vedios of lynda.com about titanium appcelerator . it took me a hour to learn .really

Comment: Fair warning -- Titanium has its problems too.  It provides a layer between your code and the iOS system - their custom SDK libraries that your javascript calls.  Bugs or limitations in the Titanium SDK will cause bugs or limitations in your app.  It's a trade-off.  They make your development "easier", but you're at the mercy of their speed and reliability.

Answer (score 8):

PhoneGap and Titanium work in very different ways.

[PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com) essentially creates an embedded Safari browser, then runs whatever HTML you provide it.  For the most part, anything you can do in mobile Safari you could do in PhoneGap -- use AJAX, consume web services, CSS3 animations, etc.

[Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/platform/titanium-sdk/) is a different beast.  It lets you code your app using JavaScript, then compiles to a native iOS app.  They provide a js SDK, and you use that to tell the system what you want to do (create a tab bar; show a button; draw a label; etc.).  Your JavaScript is then packaged along with their custom libraries to create a native iPhone or iPad app.  The views, buttons and objects you get are the native controls, not html elements.  You don't get exactly the same performance of an app developed by hand in Xcode and Objective-C, but it tends to be slightly faster than what PhoneGap does.

Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Speaking of Phonegap, you can use any javascript library like jquery etc. I think there should be libraries for all of these cases. For example, I already used a webservice with the jquery.ajax() function.

I think Titanium is similar in this aspect, but the user interface is not described in html but also in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked on PhoneGap and can hence help you with that.

- XML Parsing: supported by native javascript function calls, no library required.
- Ajax: this again is supported by javascript, no external library required. However, for easy control, you can use jQuery.
- Remote XML file parsing: haven't worked on parsing files, but yes javascript allows you to parse xml received via ajax responses.
- Web Service support: have implemented SOAP services, hope Restful should also be supported.

In case you need further help, do write back.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, Phonegap and Titanium work very differently.  I use Titanium but also understand that I am writing to their javascript api.  This eventually gets compiled down to the native ios or android SDK.  So Titanium apps are more native than PhoneGap apps.

To answer your questions:

1. yes it supports XML parsing and has an entire library available to work with XML documents
2. Titanium lets you use any Javascript library you wish, and with the new Titanium 3.0 the underscore library is already included.
3. I work with remote files all the time.  You will be able to make a request to any web service or 3rd party API to retrieve data
4. Absolutely.  I have integrated with my own custom REST API hosted in Azure as well as called a 3rd party weather API

Answer (score 0):

Just a little more info for this thread. PhoneGap is now [Apache Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/). The differences between Cordova and Titanium can be summed as this:

- Cordova is a webview, Titanium is a javascript sdk that compiles your    app into native iOS and Android platforms.
- Cordova apps can be downloaded straight from the Internet. Titanium    apps need to submit to the Apple/Google vetting processes to be available for mass consumption.

Hope this quick blurb adds to your understanding. If not, simply ignore it. :D

Edit: iOS and Android apps created in Cordova also need to be submitted to their respective app stores. I misspoke earlier.