# Choose between PhoneGap & Titanium

Tags: cordova, titanium

So, I have to develop a mobile application and
I want to use Phonegap or Titanium but I need advice about those technologies...

Are they for free?
What are their limitations?

I don't really understand them and I want to have more information before I start coding...

Thanks!

Comment: I just started developing with Cordova, for free. I couldn't find the free download page of Appcelerator though.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Both Phonegap and Titanium are free for developing mobile application and to develop apps using Titanium, you should need basic knowledge in javascript since it is simple javascript combined with [Titanium API](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api) while we can use most of web technologies like HTML, Javascript, CSS etc. **It's purely depend on what type of application you want to create**. More simply if you want to create simple app that does not contain graphs and drawings you can simply use Titanium but if your app contains graphs you should use Phonegap.

Please refer the following links. Each can answer your question.

1. [Comparing Titanium And Phonegap - Appcelerator blog](http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2012/05/comparing-titanium-and-phonegap.html)
2. [Titanium and Phonegap](http://kevinwhinnery.com/post/22764624253/comparing-titanium-and-phonegap)
3. [Comparison Between Corona Phonegap Titanium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482586/comparison-between-corona-phonegap-titanium)
4. [Phonegap vs Titanium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772177/phonegap-vs-titanium)
5. [Phonegap or Appcelerator Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15162228/phonegap-or-appcelerator-implementation)
6. [Doubts on using Phonegap and Titanium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14773239/doubts-on-using-phonegap-and-titanium)
7. [Appcelerator Titanium vs. Phonegap: Which is the better Mobile Development Platform?](http://mobile.dzone.com/news/appcelerator-titanium-vs)

You can see the pricing and plans below:

1. [Titanium Plans and Pricing](http://www.appcelerator.com/plans-pricing/)
2. [Phonegap build pricing plans update](http://phonegap.com/2011/10/13/phonegap-build-pricing-plans-update/)

**Update:** Appcelerator has updated their pricing and it is not free right now. You need to pay $39 for getting an indie seat in Appcelerator.

Comment: Important note: Titanium and Appcelerator are not interchangeable. Titanium refers to the open source platform for creating/compiling/deploying apps while Appcelerator is a company that now offers tools and cloud services for Titanium developers. There is no fee for using Titanium.