# using Phonegap ,appcelerator can develop apps like pure android and IOS

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, appcelerator-mobile

I heard that  phonegap and appcelerator develop android and IOS by using html javascript and css  .but i confused can it implement all functionality that we do by using pure android development like HTTP requests ,Bluetooth connection apps and sqlite DB connection apps and also android and IOS games.Is it possible to do these kind apps by using phonegap or appcelerator. what are the limitations of these frame work.

Thank you

Comment: You might find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17249500/xamarin-2-0-vs-appcelerator-titanium-vs-phonegap/17263729#17263729 helpful

Answer (score 0):

For Appcelerator, the answer is that there are some native functions on each platform that you cannot use directly from Appcelerator.  You can definitely use sqlite on both platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Both Phonegap and Titanium are free for developing mobile application and to develop apps using Titanium, you should need basic knowledge in javascript since it is simple javascript combined with [Titanium API](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api) while we can use most of web technologies like HTML, Javascript, CSS etc. **It's purely depend on what type of application you want to create**. More simply if you want to create simple app that does not contain graphs and drawings you can simply use Titanium but if your app contains graphs you should use Phonegap.

Please refer the following links. Each can answer your question.

1. [Comparing Titanium And Phonegap - Appcelerator blog](http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2012/05/comparing-titanium-and-phonegap.html)
2. [Titanium and Phonegap](http://kevinwhinnery.com/post/22764624253/comparing-titanium-and-phonegap)
3. [Comparison Between Corona Phonegap Titanium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482586/comparison-between-corona-phonegap-titanium)
4. [Phonegap vs Titanium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772177/phonegap-vs-titanium)
5. [Phonegap or Appcelerator Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15162228/phonegap-or-appcelerator-implementation)
6. [Doubts on using Phonegap and Titanium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14773239/doubts-on-using-phonegap-and-titanium)
7. [Appcelerator Titanium vs. Phonegap: Which is the better Mobile Development Platform?](http://mobile.dzone.com/news/appcelerator-titanium-vs)
8. [Xamarin 2.0 vs Appcelerator Titanium vs PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17249500/xamarin-2-0-vs-appcelerator-titanium-vs-phonegap/17263729#17263729)

You can see the pricing and plans below:

1. [Titanium Plans and Pricing](http://www.appcelerator.com/plans-pricing/)
2. [Phonegap build pricing plans update](http://phonegap.com/2011/10/13/phonegap-build-pricing-plans-update/)

Comment: Is it better to learn one of these framework or stick on native android and IOS development ?

Comment: @SAGA: Building a cross-platform app will reduce human effort, time and money. For eg: Imaging you want to create a simple application that takes 2 man days to complete, if you do it in native code you may take atleast 3 days to finish it for both platform but if you use any cross platform like titanium/phonegap you can do the same in 2 man days or less. From my own experience as a cross platform developer, It is always better to use cross-platform than go to native